# Help with infimums

Tags: analysis

Suppose S ⊆ R is non-empty and bounded below. Suppose that M
is a greatest lower bound for S and that N is also a greatest lower bound for S.
Prove that M = N. (This shows that the greatest lower bound of S is unique)

I don't know where to begin to start this question can anyone help me?

Comment: Begin by searching.

Answer (score 0):

since $N$ is glb then $M\leq N$ and since $M$ is glb then $N\leq M$ so $M=N$.

I have used the definition:

A lower bound $a$ of $S$ is called an infimum (or greatest lower bound, or meet) of $S$ if

for all lower bounds $y$ of $S$, $y ≤ a$ ($a$ is larger than any other lower bound).